# Unclosed square bracket doesn't throw error in jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, safari, square-bracket

```
$('#parent_tab [href="#tab1"').click();
```

The above line works fine and the tab gets selected in other browsers but not safari. I had to close the square bracket of href as follows in order to make it work in Safari.

```
$('#parent_tab [href="#tab1"]').click();
```

Why did jquery not throw an error when the square bracket is not closed?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's a Safari issue. Another reason is because the closing bracket is inside the jQuery selector. Safari might be concerned only with JavaScript code outside jQuery selector. It is just a text that can have different format and jQuery just tries to interpret it.

You can also try the following code if it will throw an error.

```
$("#parent_tab [href='#tab1'").click();
```

Comment: This line is same as the one I reported. It doesn't throw error in any browser

Answer (score 1):

The CSS spec says that it's okay to leave off the bracket. Since jQuery passes the selector along to the native `querySelectorAll` first for performance, and that method does not throw an error (plus it returns the correct element), the missing bracket isn't detected. If you used a jQuery-specific selector like `:animated` the string would go through jQuery's Sizzle selector engine and you would get an error.

https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/15199

Answer (score 1):

I was getting exactly the same error with Safari only. I tried the site on several other browsers and they had no problem.

Interestingly, in Chrome, it seems to automatically add the missing bracket when I view the source in the Dev Tools window.

Chrome Version: 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)